# An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidCastException' occurred

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

I've received this error, I know it's because you can't link tabs with keys, but I want to know how I can make these keys play sounds only when you're on the specified tab (this is the default tab so you'd start in it)
Page1 is the name of my tab.
[Here's an image of what that looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EVhNR.png)

And here's what I have so far, it's triggering my error:

```
  Private Sub CaseKeysPage1(sender As Object, e As KeyEventArgs) Handles Page1.Enter
    Select Case e.KeyCode
        Case Keys.Q
            My.Computer.Audio.Play(My.Resources.How_are_you, AudioPlayMode.Background)
    End Select
End Sub
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Your error occurs because `Enter` event does not send `KeyEventArgs`.Try using `Page1.KeyDown` event instead of `Page1.Enter`

Comment: That was my original code for the buttons, but sadly there is no page1.KeyDown instead, it's Page1.PreviewKeyDown which has an error. Upon compiling while continuing with this error, it throws the exact same error as before. http://imgur.com/a/g2NuM - the error.

Comment: To use `Page1.PreviewKeyDown`you must change your method definition, especially `e As PreviewKeyDownEventArgs`, let me know if it helps.

Comment: Thanks, that did the trick, my bad, I forgot to replace  KeyEventArgs with System.Windows.Forms.PreviewKeyDownEventArgs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is from Misery's comment

> To use Page1.PreviewKeyDown you must change your method definition, especially e As PreviewKeyDownEventArgs, let me know if it helps.

Therefore my code has changed to

```
Private Sub Page1_PreviewKeyDown(sender As Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.PreviewKeyDownEventArgs) Handles Page1.PreviewKeyDown
    Select Case e.KeyCode
        Case Keys.Q
            My.Computer.Audio.Play(My.Resources.How_are_you, AudioPlayMode.Background)
   End Select
End Sub
```